# Incorrect field id in netflow v9

Tags: python, cisco, netflow

While analyzing Netflow V9, I am able to get most of the fields ids correctly along with their values as that is defined in

http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipfix/ipfix.xml

but I am getting 40000 ,40001, 40002, ...   instead of 224, 225, 226, ... for NAT fileds,
however the values for each fields I retrieved are correct.

I am certain that all fields' id and value are correctly obtained.
I don't know what is the real problem. I tried with conversion of host to network byte and vice versa using

```
field_type = socket.ntohs(struct.unpack('H', template_data[a:b])[0])
```

P.S. I used cisco router for netflow v9.

Comment: There isn't much way for us to help unless you post more information for why you think 224, 225, 226 are correct instead of 40000, 40001, 40002.  A packet capture of the packet that triggered the netflow export, as well as the export values itself would make this question answerable.

Comment: Although I doubt this is at fault, make sure you're unpacking values in network byte order: '>H'.

Comment: @MikePennington

Wireshark Inception shows:
DstPort : 80,
SrcAddr : 192.168.15.217,
SrcPort : 52496,
Post NAPT Source Transport Port : 16978,
Post NAPT Destination Transport Port : 80,
and so on ... 
but what I got while analyzing myself is:
destination_port : 80
source_address : 192.168.15.217
source_port : 52496,
Unknown_field_40003 : 16978,
Unknown_filed_40004 : 80
...
where 40003 and 40004 are field ids I retrieved but link to ipfix.xml shows it should have been 227, 228 for NAPT ports.
40000's fields ids are not defined in netflow rfc as well, However values to each obtained are correct.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis 
yes I could use '>H' but that only avoid the use `socket.ntohs` however the problem remains as it is.

Comment: @Zangetsu is your code for parsing Netflow v9 open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco doesn't use IPFIX, but NetFlow v9.  Although IPFIX is derived from Cisco's NetFlow v9 specification, there are some differences.  One of them is that IPFIX allows for per-vendor namespaces in the field type numbers using the PrivateEnterpriseNumber.   NetFlow v9 does not have such a facility, therefore vendors have to arbitrarily choose a range of numbers to report their custom fields on and hope no one else picks the same range.   In this case, I'm guessing your getting your NetFlow tickets from Cisco ASA, which indeed uses a number of fields in the range of 40000-40005.

There is a document called '[Cisco ASA 5500 Series Implementation Note for NetFlow Collectors, 8.3](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa83/netflow/netflow.html)' which describes those fields.

Comment: Oh yes! thanks man. Such a relief that I didn't do it wrong :)